# upload an image file to sharepoint via api graph

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload an image file from my node.js application to a group's drive in Sharepoint.

As the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0) states, I'm making my request as follows:

```
PUT /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
```

With the binary image in the body: "The contents of the request body should be the binary stream of the file to be uploaded."

The problem is that the image is uploaded but as a corrupted file. I tried different solutions and still don't see why is always the image corrupted.

Here is my code:

```
//i get my image from a URL first
https.get(url.parse(attachment.contentUrl), function (response) {
    var data = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(data);
        //store my image in a local file to test if image is correct (which it is)
        fs.writeFile(localFileName, buffer, (fsError) => {
            //error handling
        });
        functions.uploadImageToSharepoint(session, localFileName, buffer, 
            function (err, body, res) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }else{
                    console.log('OK!');
                }
            });
      } else {
        //error handling
      }
    });
}).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("error2: " + e);
});

//and the request to graph api
function uploadImageToSharepoint(session, fileName, data, callback) {
  var options = {
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xxxxxxx/drive/root:/yyyyyy/fileName.jpg:/content', 
    method: 'PUT',
    body: data,
    json: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session.userData.accessToken
    }    
  };

  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) return callback(err, body, res);
    if (parseInt(res.statusCode / 100, 10) !== 2) {
        if (body.error) {
            return callback(new Error(res.statusCode + ': ' + (body.error.message || body.error)), body, res);
        }
        return callback(err, body, res);
    }
    callback(err, body ,res);   
  });  
}
```

Comment: Is `localFileName` also corrupt?

Comment: Local files were saved correctly, the problem was the json:true option, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is most likely  getting corrupted due to the following option for request:

```
var options = {
    json: true,   //<--setting this option sets body to JSON representation of value
    //another properties are omitted for clarity
  };
```

In that case [`request`](https://github.com/request/request#readme) *sets body to JSON representation of value* and adds  [`accept` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) to `application/json` for [`Upload` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0) and binary file get corrupted.

The solution would be to omit `json` option from a request and  use the proper `content-type` only:

```
var options = {
    url: '/me/drive/root:/filename.jpg:/content', 
    method: 'PUT',
    body: data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/jpg',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }    
};
```

Comment: That's it! I've been days struggling with streams and buffers and the problem was in the request itself... Thank you @Vadim Gremyachev

Comment: It is amazing how difficult it is to find this solution. I was searching for truncated uploads instead of corrupted uploads. This did the trick!