# Graph File Upload API - Images are getting corrupted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, multipartform-data, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

When I am trying to upload image using graph EndPoint then images are getting corrupted.
Endpoint - PUT [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/items/{item_id}:/{file_name}:/content](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/%7Bdrive_id%7D/items/%7Bitem_id%7D:/%7Bfile_name%7D:/content)

Anything I am missing here?

SharePoint Message When trying to view uploaded (through above code)image. Tried without encoding as well. Even file name is not encoded then also its same behavior.

**Note -** This issue is with only images. Other files like PDF, CSV are working fine.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55919294/upload-an-image-file-to-sharepoint-via-api-graph?

Answer (score 1):

Changing form-data to binary solved my problem.

[image]